# Why am I getting PLS-00306 "wrong number or types of arguments in call" when the Hibernate looks correct?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc

I have the following...

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE (    LOAD_FLAG         in varchar2, success            OUT VARCHAR2)
```

I am trying to use it with Spring JPA like...

```
@Procedure("schema.package.UPDATE")
String update(@Param("LOAD_FLAG") String fullLoadFlag);
```

But when I run I get...

```
2021-03-29 10:56:59.315  WARN [,,,] 31256 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
2021-03-29 10:56:59.315 ERROR [,,,] 31256 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE'
```

The Hibernate is logging...

> {call schema.package.UPDATE(?,?)}

So everything looks correct so what am I missing?

Comment: Your stored procedure expects 2 input parameters it seems.

Comment: @DaviM One is an output param but I have also tried it as INOUT

Comment: Also the Hibernate mapping shows the param.

Comment: Did you try using @Prodedure attribute "outputParameterName"?

Comment: @DaviM Actually yes I did this afternoon and it worked. You are more than welcome to take the answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @Prodedure attribute "outputParameterName" like this...

```
@Procedure(value = "schema.pkg.UPDATE", outputParameterName = "success")
String update(@Param("LOAD_FLAG") String fullLoadFlag);
```

Where the output parameter name is the name of the out variable.

Comment: I updated and when the edits are approved I will accept.

Comment: Edits approved.